# How to display iOS/cupertino alert dialog in Android using Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I was trying to display a iOS themed dialog box in my Flutter app, but I was unable to find anything in the docs

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 23):

The keyword for Android theme/style is **Material** (default design), the keyword for iOS theme/style is **Cupertino**. Every iOS theme widget has the prefix **Cupertino**. So that, for you requirement, we can guess the keyword is **CupertinoDialog**/**CupertinoAlertDialog**

You can refer here for all of them https://flutter.io/docs/reference/widgets/cupertino

```
new CupertinoAlertDialog(
  title: new Text("Dialog Title"),
  content: new Text("This is my content"),
  actions: <Widget>[
    CupertinoDialogAction(
      isDefaultAction: true,
      child: Text("Yes"),
    ),
    CupertinoDialogAction(
      child: Text("No"),
    )
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 21):

### First you check if platForm ios or android .. then return widget for the current device ..

```
Future<bool> showAlertDialog({
  @required BuildContext context,
  @required String title,
  @required String content,
  String cancelActionText,
  @required String defaultActionText,
}) async {
  if (!Platform.isIOS) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text(title),
        content: Text(content),
        actions: <Widget>[
          if (cancelActionText != null)
            FlatButton(
              child: Text(cancelActionText),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
            ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text(defaultActionText),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // todo : showDialog for ios
  return showCupertinoDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
      title: Text(title),
      content: Text(content),
      actions: <Widget>[
        if (cancelActionText != null)
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            child: Text(cancelActionText),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
          ),
        CupertinoDialogAction(
          child: Text(defaultActionText),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: is any problem if we use ios alert dialog for android ?

Comment: @Adnanhaider no.

Answer (score 8):

I used **CupertinoAlertDialog** inside the **ShowDialog**, you can find the same below

```
showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: new Text("Dialog Title"),
        content: new Text("This is my content"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            isDefaultAction: true,
            child: Text(StringConstants.BIOMETRICAUTHORIZED),
          ),
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            child: Text("No"),
          )
        ],
      )
    );
```