# Text field alert dialog for multiple platforms

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm asking this question because I wasn't able to find one proper answer for implementing text field alert dialog. I basically put this thing together from multiple answers which works nicely but it doesn't switch to iOS style dialog when on iOS device. BTW Using CupertionAlertDialog throws error "no material widget found". I don't think it likes TextFormField in content

**EDITED NEW FULLY FUNCTIONAL CODE**

Here is my function file text_field_dialog.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

String _typedValue;
TextEditingController _textFieldController = TextEditingController();

Future<String> textFieldDialog({BuildContext context, String initValue}) async {
  _typedValue = initValue;
  _textFieldController.text = initValue;
  Platform.isIOS
      ? await showCupertinoDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return CupertinoAlertDialog(
              title: Text('TextField in Dialog'),
              content: Container(
                child: CupertinoTextField(
                  autofocus: true,
                  controller: _textFieldController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  placeholder: "TextField in Dialog",
                  onChanged: (v) => _typedValue = v,
                ),
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                CupertinoDialogAction(
                  isDefaultAction: true,
                  child: Text("OK"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
                CupertinoDialogAction(
                    child: new Text('CANCEL'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _typedValue = initValue;
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    }),
              ],
            );
          },
        )
      : await showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text('TextField in Dialog'),
              content: TextField(
                controller: _textFieldController,
                autofocus: true,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "TextField in Dialog"),
                onChanged: (v) => _typedValue = v,
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: new Text('OK'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: new Text('CANCEL'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _typedValue = initValue;
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            );
          },
        );
  return _typedValue;
}
```

and here is button where I call the dialog in main class

```
FlatButton(
          child: Text('show'),
          onPressed: () async {
            String h = await textFieldDialog(context: context, initValue: '5');
            print(h);
          });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53461273/how-to-display-ios-cupertino-alert-dialog-in-android-using-flutter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display iOS/cupertino alert dialog in Android using Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53461273/how-to-display-ios-cupertino-alert-dialog-in-android-using-flutter)

Comment: @PrathikJain I just edited my question. CupertinoAlertDialog throws error when TextField is in content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call the `CupertinoAlertDialog()` to show the IOS style dialog.

Comment: Thanks... yes I already noticed that from comments.. I just tried that but I don't think the CupertinoAlertDialog likes TextFormField in the content.. No Material widget found error

Comment: Just found an answer for this problem. I have to use CupertinoTextField together with CupertinoAlertDialog or wrap TextField into a card